# NDSolve printing error message NDSolve::ndode

Tags: plotting

Using `NDSolve` while solving system of ODE's. Here is my try

```
Eqn1 = -C  f'''''[x] + f'''[x] + f[x]  f''[x] - f'[x]  f'[x] + r^2 + λ  T[x] == 0   

Eqn2 = 
  T''[x] + p1 f[x] T'[x] + 
    p2/(3 (1 - tw)) (12 (tw + (1 - tw) T[x] ) + tw)^2 (1 - tw) T'[x] T'[x] +  
    4 ((1 - tw) T[x] + tw)^3 (1 - tw) T''[x] == 0

BC1 = f[0] == 0
BC2 = f'[0] == 1
BC3 = f'[10] == r
BC4 = f''[10] == 0
BC5 = f'''[10] == 0
BC6 = T'[0] == -B (1 - T[0])
BC7 = T[10] == 0

param = {λ -> 1, p1 -> 10, B -> 10, tw -> 1.5, p2 -> 0.5, 
  C -> 1, r -> 1}

Sol = 
  NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4, BC5, BC6, BC7} /. param, 
    {f, T}, {x, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> 
      {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
        {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == 1, f'''[0] == 0, f''''[0] == 0, T[0] = 0}}]
```

But I'm getting this error

> NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific reason for the error message is that `"StartingInitialConditions"` contains `T[0] = 0`.  It should be `T[0] == 0`.  The fact that `f'[0] == 0` is inconsistent with `BC2` and that there are too few `"StartingInitialConditions"` for `T` also may cause difficulties.  Certainly, with `f'[0] == 0` and `T'[0] == -10` added, the integration proceeds further before encountering

```
NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == 9.991371232789929`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

This last issue suggests that the `NDSolve` `Method` may need to be reconsidered.

Comment: Thanks dear for pointing out the syntax error. But NDSolve is facing issues to solve the odes.

Comment: Integration will fail, if `1 + 4*(1 - tw)*(tw + T[x] - tw*T[x])^3` vanishes within the domain of integration.

Comment: if I take p2 = 0, that should make it solvable but I still get  'singularity or stiff system suspected.

Comment: I see that you made progress in 76135.  Congratulations.

Comment: yes I did but with asymptomatic boundary at 3. I would like to see the results for at least 12.

Comment: I just tried running your code exactly as in 76135, but NDSolve still produces `NDSolve::ndsz` errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21545/discussion-between-mmm-and-bbgodfrey).